# cannot move out of borrowed content in a for loop over an iterator

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement a "read line" function by implementing the `Iterator` trait.

Here, I own the `Bytes<BufReader<File>>` inside the struct. For the `next` function, I wish to loop over the iterator to find a `b'\n'`.

```
use std::io::BufReader;

struct MyStringLineBufReader {
    bytes_iter: std::io::Bytes<BufReader<std::fs::File>>,
}

impl Iterator for MyStringLineBufReader {
    type Item = (String);

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<<Self as Iterator>::Item> {
        let mut bytes: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
        for b in self.bytes_iter {
            let b = b.unwrap();
            if b == b'\n' {
                break;
            } else {
                bytes.push(b)
            }
        }
        return Some(String::from_utf8(bytes).unwrap());
    }
}
```

The code is not finished yet but I feel it should compile. I get the following message:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/lib.rs:12:18
   |
12 |         for b in self.bytes_iter {
   |                  ^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: The duplicates applied to your situation: `for b in &mut self.bytes_iter` / `for b in self.bytes_iter.by_ref()`

Comment: @Shepmaster Really appreciate your help. That works! Would you please send me the duplicated question if possible? I wish to read more about it.

Comment: the duplicate questions are listed in a box on this page; try reloading your browser.